# What is the best way to click on a tab using Java and selenium on a webpage?

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium but I have a question. On the [URL](https://www.di.se/bors/large-cap/)

I want to click the tab "Nyckeltal" (at top of the page) with the
element:

```
<a class="instrument-table-tab-menu__tab js_tab-menu__tab" data-target="table_2">Nyckeltal</a>.
```

Currently I can click the tab using the code:

```
String xpath ="/html/body/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/a[3]"; 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
```

But I guess there is a better way to do this?
I guess the path is regular changed because of ads and therefor I think using xpath is not particular good.

My question is there a better way to click "Nyckeltal" than using xpath with Selenium and if there is, how do I write?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `xPath` to click that tab.

```
//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and text()='Nyckeltal']
```

In these type of cases, you need to create a dynamic `xPath` that means same `xPath` can be used for multiple element with different values.

**Examples**: In below examples I have just changed the text of the tab.

`xPath` for `Kurser` tab.

```
//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and text()='Kurser']
```

`xPath` for `Historik` tab.

```
//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and text()='Historik']
```

I would suggest you to practice with `xPath` more. Please go through this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: Hi and ty for your answer! 
I tried example 1 and it worked but I need to scroll down at the page a little to get it working (I have a small screen 15.1"). 
"Nyckeltal" must be visible on screen to click it (only visible in inspect when visible on screen). 
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes you can scroll down till element `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)` here you need to pass the web element.

Comment: Tested WebElement elem=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and contains(@data-target,'2')]")); 
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem); but is not working!? What is wrong?

Comment: How about for instance if I want to execute getPageSource and get all stocks? Because I must scroll down to bottom of page to get all stocks with my computer which feels incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do if you have the class name with:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("PUT CLASSNAME OF ELEMENT HERE")).click();
```

Comment: I think it will return multiple results as there are multiple tags with same class name. We should use a condition and that will be possible with `xPath` or `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

You should give more precedence to css selector than xpath

`CSS` would be :

```
a[class^='instrument-table-tab-menu'][data-target$='2']
```

`XPATH` would be :

```
//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and contains(@data-target,'2')]
```

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

**Using XPATH**

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and contains(@data-target,'2')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and contains(@data-target,'2')]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and contains(@data-target,'2')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'instrument-table-tab-menu') and contains(@data-target,'2')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Hi and ty for your answer! 
I tried example 1 and it worked but I need to scroll down at the page a little to get it working (I have a small screen 15.1"). 
"Nyckeltal" must be visible on screen to click it (only visible in inspect when visible on screen). 
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Even I am working on 15.1 inches. I could click on it. When you run my first code, what error have you got ?